# identity federation : one idp with 2 service providers and to share information between this 2 service providers

Tags: identity, federation

Suppose one organization [OrgA] is using 2 Saas application services[OrgB and OrgC] .
OrgB and OrgC is federating identity with OrgA ,using which employees of OrgA[Azure Active Directory] can single sign-on to the OrgB's Saas application [Resident IDP/Mediator] site and use their service. IN the same way OrgA's employees can access orgC's data
OrgA ->trust relation  ->OrgB
OrgA ->trust relation ->OrgC

OrgB has tie up with OrgC and they provide inbuilt connector to OrgC so that they can share the data.OrgA buys a license to this connector, so that OrgB and OrgC can share the data of OrgA employees related to the service

OrgB ->trust relation ->OrgC
Question

I understand the internals of establishing trust between 1 st layer of Third party services.But could not find any information on the following

How is OrgA's 4th Party[OrgC] is establishing trust with OrgB ,so that OrgB is able to share OrgA's data with OrgC?

What is the connector doing internally?[ Connector between OrgB and OrgC]